# Is it a sin to plot data when you don't have a test set?

Tags: overfitting, vc-dimension

Let's say I have an Excel workbook containing data I want to analyse.

I plot the data in Excel and see it has roughly a linear shape. Therefore, I use Excel to draw me the fitted line and brag to my manager that I found some new insights.

Unfortunately, if the plot had roughly the shape of $x^2$, $x^3$, $\sqrt{x}$ or $e^x$, I would have probably also recognized it. Through the plot, my mind automatically tried to fit any of those models and probably others ($log(x)$ for instance) which could lead to overfitting.

**Can I plot data, look at the plot, fit a model, and get reliable results if i don't have a test set?**

More generally, **should ALL statistical analysis have a test dataset ?**

Comment: Such general are always wrong (except this one of course ). In many applications I am aware of a test set is just impractical or even impossible.

Comment: What you are doing is exploratory data analysis.   It will often result in overfitting or the discovery of spurious relationships (the history of science is full of examples) , and is better suited to the construction of hypotheses to be tested with new data with the aim of confirming the result.  Two ways to get new data is to collect some more, or to have held back some data as a test set before doing the exploratory data analysis; if neither is possible, then you may have problems

Comment: Thank you MaartenBuis and @Henry for your useful comments!